# What's the difference between stationary and still?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, difference, vocabulary

For instance:

1. The bus is still.
2. The bus is stationary.

When do we use each of them?

- Also, why in the idiom "sit still", still looks like an adverb?
- Is there an adverb that has the same meaning of "still" or
  "stationary"?

Comment: **Still** can be either an adjective or an adverb (also a verb or noun!). Please check out an [online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/still).

Answer (score 2):

Being **stationary** concerns movement from point A to point B, while **still** refers to movement in-place.

Water boiling in a kettle, or a child sitting in a chair waving its arms around are stationary (they stay in one place, without changing position in space), but not still (as they do move in-place). If you're sitting in a wheelchair that's rolling down a hill, you're still, but not stationary.